# Zero length struct: what's the pointer pointing at?

Tags: c, struct, memory-management

I've been playing around with C and came across this case.

There's two zero width structs, `C` and `D` where `D` contains `C`.

As we can see, the pointer to the zero length struct `b` has an address that is one byte offset from the also zero length struct `a` (see output below).

In this case, what do the `&a` and `&b` addresses point to?

Why is there one byte offset between them?

Shouldn't they both be `null` pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct C {};

struct D {
    struct C wreck;
};

int main () {

    struct C a;
    struct D b;

    printf("struct C a size %lu stored at %p\n", sizeof(a), &a);
    printf("struct D b size %lu stored at %p\n", sizeof(b), &b);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./struc 
struct C a size 0 stored at 0x7ffe05c8b6e6
struct D b size 0 stored at 0x7ffe05c8b6e7
```

Compiler used:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
```

Comment: This is probably because the smallest allocation unit is one byte. If they were NULL pointers they wouldn't "exist".

Comment: FYI, structure declarations should not be empty in strictly conforming C. `struct C {}` is either C++ or a compiler extension.

Comment: An interesting experiment would be to define an array of these and see its size. *Update*: in fact just did it and it is zero, which makes sense from the pointer arithmetic perspective.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That is interesting because it means `&a[0]` and `&a[1]` must have the same address, which violates the rule in C 2018 6.5.8 5 that pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements with lower subscript values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, exactly what I commented under the answer. These are indeed equal in my experiment.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There is a difference. 6.5.9, for equality, allows two pointers to compare equal if one “happens” to immediately follow the first in the address space. So if `x` is at address 100 and is zero bytes long, 100 is immediately “after” it, and `y`, also at 100, can compare equal to it. But 6.5.8, for relational operators, does not have that exception.

Comment: I think the first reply, by @EricPostpischil is the correct answer. This is invalid C.

Comment: @JoseFonseca: I did not say it was invalid C. I said it was not strictly conforming. The C standard also allows conforming C code, which is anything accepted by some compiler that also accepts strictly conforming C code. And there is also non-standard C, which is valid because the C standard is voluntary. People are allowed to make their own variants.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You said this is either C++ or a compiler extension. I believe that was a good enough answer to my question, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> what do the &a and &b addresses point to?

`&a` is the address of a struct of type `C`, and `&b` is the address of a struct of type `D`. It is the same as if the structures were of non-zero size. Why would it be any different?

> Why is there one byte offset between them?

Because the standard requires that two separate values cannot have the same address. But the single byte at the `&a` location is, of course, not part of `a` itself; it's padding the compiler is forced to insert.

> Shouldn't they both be `null` pointers?

No. Why should they be? The structs named `a` and `b` exist. The fact that they don't contain any data, doesn't count against their existence. `&a` is the address of `a`; expecting `&a` to be null is like expecting to be able to do `*(NULL)` without invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: *Because the standard requires that two separate values cannot have the same address* - how does it align with having `struct C a[10];` and having `&a[0]` equal to `&a[1]` ?

Comment: About your first question, why would it be any different? Because if we dereference this pointer, we get a pointer to zero bytes. I don't think this is conformant to C standard. I think the answer by Eric Postpichil on the original post is the correct one: this is invalid C.